# How to change the current folder on Delphi?

Tags: delphi, filesystems

How to change process current folder on Delphi?

Comment: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/XE5/en/ChDir_(Delphi)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both ways work: `ChDir` or `SetCurrentDir`. They both make the same Windows API call: `SetCurrentDirectory`.

If you use `ChDir`, an exception will be raised (in `$I+` mode_) if the directory doesn't exist. So you'd want to handle the exception in that case (using `try` and `except`).

If you use `SetCurrentDir`, it will return `false` if the directory doesn't exist, and `true` if it was successful.

Given that `SetCurrentDir` is newer and `ChDir` is quite old, legacy (from DOS days), the former is preferred and easy to use as well.

Comment: If you want a custom error message on failure, I'd definitely choose `SetCurrentDir`. Generally, I'd avoid using `try..finally` to display 'custom' error messages.

Comment: `ChDir` is legacy Pascal, akin to old school Pascal I/O. Exceptions only raised in $I+ mode.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand, either case allows you to do a custom error message. However, it is certainly cleaner and probably preferrable to use `SetCurrentDir`. It's a newer call. `ChDir` goes back to the DOS Pascal days.

Answer (score 5):

Call the [`SetCurrentDir`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.SetCurrentDir) function from the `SysUtils` unit.

Note that the current directory is not a system property, it is a property of the process. Each process has its own current directory.